# How to simplify quantmod commands to load stock data

Tags: r, quantmod

If I want to load stock data, this is how I do it (for Google as an example):

```
## most recent close price
getSymbols("GOOG")
last(GOOG)[,4]

## total equity
getFinancials("GOOG")
viewFinancials(GOOG.f, type='BS', period='A',subset = NULL)['Total Equity',1]

## Net Income
viewFinancials(GOOG.f, type='IS', period='Q',subset = NULL)['Net Income',1]
```

...the list goes on.

But it would be much more practical to have to type `GOOG` only once and then have it replaced with a generic name in the rest of the code. How can this be done in `quantmod`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `auto.assign=FALSE` should solve the problem.

Below is a modified version of your code. Extending it to a larger number of tickers and treating them, e.g., in a loop should be straightforward.

```
library(quantmod)
CollectionOfTickers <- c("GOOG")
IndexOfCurrentTicker <- 1
# the part that follows could be extracted as a function
CurrentTicker <- getSymbols(CollectionOfTickers[IndexOfCurrentTicker], auto.assign=FALSE)
Cl(last(CurrentTicker)) ## most recent close price
## total equity
CurrentTickerFinancials <- getFinancials(CollectionOfTickers[IndexOfCurrentTicker], auto.assign=FALSE)
viewFinancials(CurrentTickerFinancials, type='BS', period='A',subset = NULL)['Total Equity',1]

## Net Income
viewFinancials(CurrentTickerFinancials, type='IS', period='Q',subset = NULL)['Net Income',1]
```

Note that "GOOG" is no longer hard-coded. It is defined only once, in the vector `CollectionOfTickers` and the entry of this vector is retrieved by using the variable `IndexOfCurrentTicker` which could represent a looping variable in a larger collection of tickers.

---

**Edit**

A variant of this code to perform a loop over several tickers could be programmed like this:

```
library(quantmod)
CollectionOfTickers <- c("GOOG","AAPL","TSLA","MSFT")
for (TickerName in CollectionOfTickers) {
  CurrentTicker <- getSymbols(TickerName, auto.assign=FALSE)
  cat("========\nData for ticker ", TickerName,"\n")
  ## most recent close price:
  print(Cl(last(CurrentTicker))) 
  CurrentTickerFinancials <- getFinancials(TickerName, auto.assign=FALSE)
  ## total equity:
  print(viewFinancials(CurrentTickerFinancials, type='BS', period='A',subset = NULL)['Total Equity',1])
  ## Net Income:
  print(viewFinancials(CurrentTickerFinancials, type='IS', period='Q',subset = NULL)['Net Income',1])
  cat("========\n")
}
```

The code quality could be improved by some further refactoring, but in any case this should work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, that works. If I had, say, four stocks `c("GOOG","AAPL","TSLA","MSFT")` how would I loop the command to get four separate output (one per each stock)?

Comment: thanks, that helps. Why the need of 'print' function when performing a loop?

Comment: The `print()` command is necessary to redirect the output to the console when the code is stored in a script like `myscript.r` and run from within an R session with `source('myscript.r')`. The curly braces after the `for` loop represent a scope from which the output may need to be retrieved explicitly.

Comment: I know I keep moving the target, but instead of this format would it be possible to generate a data frame with stock names as row names?

Comment: @Oposum I'm glad that I could help. Generating a data.frame with this data is not very difficult. Maybe a good start would be to define an empty data.frame with the required row and column names and fill its entries within the loop by assigning the values to the corresponding cells instead of using `print()`. Since this deviates quite significantly from the original question I'd suggest that you try to see how far you can get and post a new question if you encounter difficulties. I believe that introducing big changes of the topic within a question won't help other / future readers.

Comment: I have another question without answer, concerning avoiding hardcoding, maybe you could help there too: (stackoverflow.com/questions/36973452/importing-10-year-history-of-company-financials)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.  If you need something else...post back...

```
require(XML)
require(plyr)

getKeyStats_xpath <- function(symbol) {
  yahoo.URL <- "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="
  html_text <- htmlParse(paste(yahoo.URL, symbol, sep = ""), encoding="UTF-8")

  #search for <td> nodes anywhere that have class 'yfnc_tablehead1'
  nodes <- getNodeSet(html_text, "/*//td[@class='yfnc_tablehead1']")

  if(length(nodes) > 0 ) {
    measures <- sapply(nodes, xmlValue)

    #Clean up the column name
    measures <- gsub(" *[0-9]*:", "", gsub(" \\(.*?\\)[0-9]*:","", measures))   

    #Remove dups
    dups <- which(duplicated(measures))
    #print(dups) 
    for(i in 1:length(dups)) 
      measures[dups[i]] = paste(measures[dups[i]], i, sep=" ")

    #use siblings function to get value
    values <- sapply(nodes, function(x)  xmlValue(getSibling(x)))

    df <- data.frame(t(values))
    colnames(df) <- measures
    return(df)
  } else {
    # break
    cat("Could not find",symbol,"\n")
    return(data.frame(NA))
  }
}


tickers <- c("AXP","BA","CAT","CSCO","CVX","DD","DIS","GE","GS","HD","IBM","INTC","JNJ","JPM","KO","MCD","MMM","MRK","MSFT","NKE","PFE","PG","T","TRV","UNH","UTX","V","VZ","WMT","XOM")
stats <- ldply(tickers, getKeyStats_xpath)
stats <- stats[!rowSums(is.na(stats)) == length(stats),]
rownames(stats) <- tickers
write.csv(t(stats), "FinancialStats_updated.csv",row.names=TRUE)
```